# How to get only the max row number row of record?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Below query results the record as follows ..

How to get only the max row number row of record?  I have run this query for over 20,000 records to identify duplication and get the most recent date and its number of processed (RowNumber).

```
select [FileName], ProcessDate,
ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by [FileName] order by [FileName] desc) RowNumber 
from  StagingTable
where filename = 'abc.txt'
```

[image]

Comment: So what number would you like to get in return, 1 or 4? not really clear what you're asking.

Comment: for every file, i need to get ONLY the recent date and its row number. Max  row of record. Not all the row of record.

Comment: why row number at all, just use a max?

Comment: rownumber gives me the totalcount processed

Comment: i need how many times, that file was processed and when is the most recent date of that file processed..

Comment: so does count(*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your logic, there does not seem to be a maximum row number. Or is the row numbering tied to another field than `ProcessDate`?

As far as I understand your problem, I would just use the following query:

```
SELECT [FileName], MAX([ProcessDate]) AS [ProcessDate], COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM [StagingTable]
GROUP BY [FileName]
```

Comment: If i populate the result of my original query to a temp  table and run your query .. i am getting the result. But rownumber count is giving as 3.

Comment: SELECT [FileName], MAX([ProcessDate]) AS [ProcessDate], Max(RowNumber)
FROM #T GROUP BY [FileName]     -- This works for me

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a filter?

```
select s.*
from (select [FileName], ProcessDate,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by [FileName] order by ProcessDate desc) as RowNumber 
      from StagingTable
      where filename = 'abc.txt'
     ) s
where RowNumber = 1;
```

Note that the `ORDER BY` has changed.

If you want the total count as well, then add then in as an additional column:

```
select s.*
from (select [FileName], ProcessDate,
             count(*) over (partition by filename) as cnt,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by [FileName] order by ProcessDate desc) as RowNumber 
      from StagingTable
      where filename = 'abc.txt'
     ) s
where RowNumber = 1;
```

Comment: sorry .. but this is not the one.. i can use cte .. syntax to get this.. Expected result.. i need to have the top row of values .. including the value # 4.

Comment: yes.. please.. total count is very helpful.. that is what expected.. :)

Comment: syntax doesnt give correct result.. when we remove the filename parameter..

Answer (score 0):

Your query has an error: in the `OrderBy` you wrote FileName, but I guess you're using the date.

You can double on the ROW_NUMBER() columns:

```sql
WITH VersionSorting AS (
  select
    [FileName],
    ProcessDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by [FileName] order by [ProcessDate] ASC) FileVersion,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by [FileName] order by [ProcessDate] DESC) FileVersionInv
  from  StagingTable
)
SELECT FileName, ProcessDate, FileVersion
FROM VersionSorting
WHERE FileVersionInv = 1
-- AND FileName = 'abc.txt'
```